# Do two-thirds of Americans believe that Congress needs to act on a climate crisis?

Tags: climate-change, science

In comments about the Green New Deal on Feb 14, 2019, US Senator Chuck Schumer [said](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/02/14/schumer-green-new-deal-1175513):

> "I challenge Leader McConnell to say that our climate change crisis is real, that it’s caused by humans, and that Congress needs to act," Schumer said on the Senate floor. "This is what two-thirds of the American people agree with."

Is this what two-thirds of Americans believe?  How does Senator Schumer know this?

Comment: This question would fit better at Skeptics than here. It does not have much to do with politics, it's just fact-checking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For at least the first two points, it's possible to find supporting polling data. An [IPSOS poll](http://climatecommunication.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Climate-Change-American-Mind-December-2018.pdf) for the Yale Program on Climate Change Communication (climatecommunication.yale.edu) and the George Mason University Center for Climate Change Communication (climatechangecommunication.org) of 1,114 adult Americans conducted in November and December 2018 found

- 73% answered yes to "Do you think that global warming is happening?" (No 14%, Don't Know 13%)
- 62% thought "assuming global warming is happening it is mostly caused by humans" (23% caused by natural changes 8% neither, it's not happening, 6% other.

Both of those figures round neatly to "two-thirds". I can't immediately find any polling over the need for action from government. However a [NBC News/Wall Street Journal poll](http://media1.s-nbcnews.com/i/today/z_creative/181489NBCWSJDecemberPoll.pdf) of 900 American adults does have 66% thinking that either "Global climate change has been established as a serious problem, and immediate action is necessary" (45%) or "There is enough evidence that climate change is taking place and
some action should be taken" (21%).

Comment: I don't see 62% anywhere (https://epic.uchicago.edu/sites/default/files/Full%20poll%20AP-NORC%202019.pdf?mc_cid=d2afa68288&mc_eid=3a0a0b27b4)... isn't that 60%?

Comment: @elliotsvensson Page 26, the second table in my link. You've found a different poll with similar results.

Comment: Is your 62% number "62% of the 73% who said yes"? Otherwise, you have 27% saying no or don't know, but 62+23 = 85% saying it happens because of humans or natural changes.

Comment: @barrycarter That is indeed what the tables for that poll say. Note that the questions are slightly different "Do you think that global warming is happening?" versus "Assuming global warming is happening, do you think it is...". The numbers for the second question are thus somewhat softer (and less repeatable) than the first.